# Video Doesn't Work on Android

Tags: html, video

I have a video embedded in my HTML site like this,

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
    <source src="Folder/Video.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="Folder/Video.webm"  type="video/webm" />
    <source src="Folder/Video/IntroductiontoRAMMPatrol.ogv"  type="video/ogg" />
        <object width="1280" height="720" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Folder/Video.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="Folder/Video.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=Folder/Video.png&amp;file=Folder/Video.MP4" />
        <img src="Folder/Video.png" width="1280" height="720" alt="Video" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>       
</video>
```

It works on some platforms, but it doesn't work on Android. If I browse to this page with Androids stock browser it doesn't work, and also with Opera Mobile. It just spins forever.

UPDATE:

I removed the flash stuff and made it like this,

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
    <source src="Folder/Video.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="Folder/Video.webm"  type="video/webm" />
    <source src="Folder/Video/IntroductiontoRAMMPatrol.ogv"  type="video/ogg" />     
</video>
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but that should work fine on my PC right? It doesn't which would explain why it wasn't working on Android. Perhaps the files that are being lnked to don't exist.

UPDATE2:

I fixed the links and it works on my PC which proves that the mp4 video is playing on my machine (whereas before the other three were failing and it was dropping back to the flash video).

But it still doesn't work on Android.

Comment: I think he made webpage with a video on it. He wants it to play properly in the browser whenever a user is on his site. Not from an application that he created to display the page. Is that correct @peter?

Comment: It's on a website, http://www.ramm.co.nz/manuals/RAMM%20Training%20Videos/index.htm#25479.htm

Comment: you might have better luck if you tag with html or some web technology.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use flash you must start flash plugin first. 
But I am not sure it can helps for you.

> WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
>   mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

Comment: I am trying to get the mp4 video to work. I don't really care about the flash one (unless the flash one is stopping the other one working).